# How to iterate through only mails of a specific date and not the entire folder in outlook vba

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a requirement to iterate through inbox and more specifically only today's mails.

Using the following code I am able to iterate through inbox and run another function only if the received date is today.

I want to know if there is any other way of iterating only through today's mail instead of going through the entire inbox (as the inbox of the end user has lot of mails and the current code takes a lot of time). Thanks in advance!

```
For Each item In olFolder.Items
    If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = item
            MsgBox Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "Short Date")

            recDate = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "Short Date")
            If recDate = Date Then
                MsgBox "Today's mail"
                Call CopyToServer(oMail)
            End If

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter Outlook mail items received by today from other mail items in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653347/how-to-filter-outlook-mail-items-received-by-today-from-other-mail-items-in-exce)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class instead of iterating over all items in the folder. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147584%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class helpful. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) .